# Family tree, cannot resolve child

Tags: java

I'm clueless with this task. I need to make family tree like on this

[image]

But I cannot solve child in Main.java. With every name I have to write null to child.

Here is my code : [Main.java](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Q12).
Second file: [Osoba.java](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Q0Z)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Osoba abraham = new Osoba("Abraham Simpson", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        Osoba penelope = new Osoba("Penelope Olsen", null, null, null, null, null, null,null);
        Osoba pan = new Osoba("Pan Bouvier", null, null, null, null, null,null,null);
        Osoba jackie = new Osoba("Jackie Bouvier", null, null, null, null, null,null,null);
        Osoba herb = new Osoba("Herb Powers", abraham, penelope, null, null, null,null,null);
        Osoba homer = new Osoba("Homer Simpson", abraham, penelope, null, null, null,null,null);
        Osoba marge = new Osoba("Marge Simpson", pan, jackie, null, null, null,null,null);
        Osoba selma = new Osoba ("Selma Bouvier", pan, jackie, null, null, null,null,null);
        Osoba bart = new Osoba("Bart Simpson", homer, abraham, penelope,marge, pan,jackie,null);

        bart.sestavRodokmen();
        System.out.println();
        homer.sestavRodokmen();
    }
}



public class Osoba {

    private String name;
    private Osoba father;
    private Osoba dad_grandpa;
    private Osoba dad_grandma;
    private Osoba mother;
    private Osoba mom_grandpa;
    private Osoba mom_grandma;
    private Osoba child;

    public Osoba (String name, Osoba father, Osoba dad_grandpa, Osoba dad_grandma, Osoba mother, Osoba mom_grandpa, Osoba mom_grandma, Osoba child) {
        this.name = name;
        this.father = father;
        this.dad_grandpa = dad_grandpa;
        this.dad_grandma = dad_grandma;
        this.mother = mother;
        this.mom_grandpa = mom_grandpa;
        this.mom_grandma = mom_grandma;
        this.child = child;
    }

    private String rodokmen;

    public void sestavRodokmen () {

        System.out.println("Rodokmen pro osobu: " + name);

        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Father: "+ father);
        System.out.println("Grandfather: "+ dad_grandpa);
        System.out.println("Grandmother: "+ dad_grandma);
        System.out.println("Mother: "+ mother);
        System.out.println("Grandfather: "+ mom_grandpa);
        System.out.println("Grandmother: "+ mom_grandma);
        System.out.println("Child: "+ child);

        rodokmen = "";
        System.out.println(rodokmen);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        String a = "";
        if(mother != null && father != null)
            a += name + "\n" + father + "\n" + mother +"\n" +"\n" + child;
        else
            a += name;

        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post picture, post code

Comment: @azro My apologies, will do next time.

Comment: You always pass `null` as the `child` parameter of the constructors, how do you expect `child` will not be null?

Comment: You can make your life much easier by just using a no argument constructor with Osoba and creating getters and setters for every field in the class

Comment: You don't need so many instance variables and parameters. All you need to keep track of is the mother and father, and then you can have methods such as `getMaternalGrandfather() {return mother.getFather();}`

Comment: What is the real goal ? Because only print in console will much harder than the simple prints you have. Also I would advise to not have grand-parent as attributes, you'll get them by parents of the parents

Comment: What jsheeran is getting at is that your task would be to build an actual family tree where each node/person knows its father and mother. This would allow you to build trees that span more than 3 generations (try doing it for a royal family and you'll get crazy doing it your way). When you have that you can always backtrack from a person to the parents, grand parents etc. - if you want to get the children then a person might add itself to the list of children for the father and mother, then you can iterate down the tree as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Osaba only the direct parents and/or direct children are needed.

At the time of creation of a new Osaba either a parent or a child can still not be defined.

Full freedom of order of creations would be:

```
    Osoba abraham = new Osoba("Abraham Simpson");
    Osoba penelope = new Osoba("Penelope Olsen");
    Osoba pan = new Osoba("Pan Bouvier");
    Osoba jackie = new Osoba("Jackie Bouvier");
    Osoba herb = new Osoba("Herb Powers");
    Osoba homer = new Osoba("Homer Simpson");
    Osoba marge = new Osoba("Marge Simpson");
    Osoba selma = new Osoba ("Selma Bouvier");
    Osoba bart = new Osoba("Bart Simpson");
```

And then create the ancestor graph using something like:

```
    herb.setParents(abraham, penelope);
    martha.setParents(null, penelope); // If no father.
```

Now if you want to check all Osaba: whether someone has not gotten parents, someone is not his own ancestor and so on, maybe you need a container class:

```
public class Osabas {
    private List<Osaba> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    public Osaba createOsaba(String name) {
        Osaba osaba = new Osaba(name);
        persons.add(osaba);
        return osaba;
    }

    public void drawAncestryDiagram() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest to not take care of `grand-parents` as you'll find them by parents of parents

   ```
   public Osoba(String name, Osoba father, Osoba mother, Osoba child) {
       this.name = name;
       this.father = father;
       this.mother = mother;
       this.child = child;
   }
   ```
2. The `toString()` should look a little more like follow, only names, not full info or you'll face recursivisty and have the whole family if you print like `Bart` :

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return String.join(" / ", name,
               father != null ? father.name : null,
               mother != null ? mother.name : null,
               child != null ? child.name : null);
   }
   ```
3. To print the tree in the console, you can add a tab for each new level, print the person then its father and then its mother, you need to use recursivity as you don't know the size of the family

   ```
   void sestavRodokmen(int level) {
       System.out.println(toString());
       printParentTab(level, father);
       printParentTab(level, mother);
   }

   void printParentTab(int level, Osoba parent) {
       if (parent != null) {
           for (int i = 0; i <= level; i++) {
               System.out.print("\t");
           }
           parent.sestavRodokmen(level + 1);
       }
   }
   ```
4. See [`Code Demo for result`](https://ideone.com/rOWCKD)

   ```
   Bart Simpson / Homer Simpson / Marge Simpson / null
       Homer Simpson / Abraham Simpson / Penelope Olsen / null
           Abraham Simpson / null / null / null
           Penelope Olsen / null / null / null
       Marge Simpson / Pan Bouvier / Jackie Bouvier / null
           Pan Bouvier / null / null / null
           Jackie Bouvier / null / null / null
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would tackle the problem:

First we need a class to represent a single person.

The diagram you provided seems to keep track of 4 properties:

- name
- surname
- gender
- linkage (father and mother)

This is reflected in the `Person` class.

```
static class Person{
    private Person father;
    private Person mother;
    private List<Person> children = new ArrayList<>();
    private String firstname;
    private String surname;
    private boolean isMale;
    public Person(String firstname, String surname, boolean isMale){
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.isMale = isMale;
    }
    public Person addChild(Person child){
        this.children.add(child);
        if(this.isMale){
            child.father = this;
        }else{
            child.mother = this;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void printTreeUp(){
        printTreeUp(0);
    }
    private void printTreeUp(int depth){
        String tabs = "";
        if(depth != 0){
            tabs = "";
            for(int i=0;i<depth;i++)
                tabs += "\t";
            tabs += "∟ ";
        }
        System.out.println(tabs + firstname + " " + surname + " " + (isMale ? "♂" : "♀"));
        if(father != null)
            father.printTreeUp(depth+1);
        if(mother != null)
            mother.printTreeUp(depth+1);
    }
    public void printTreeDown(){
        printTreeDown(0);
    }
    private void printTreeDown(int depth){
        String tabs = "";
        if(depth != 0){
            tabs = "∟";
            for(int i=1;i<depth;i++)
                tabs += "_";
        }
        System.out.println(tabs + firstname + " " + surname + " " + (isMale ? "♂" : "♀"));
        for(Person child : children)
            child.printTreeDown(depth+1);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I also added some methods to print the family tree.
In particular, there is `printTreeUp` which (starting at a given `Person`) will print their parents, grandparents, etc.
There is also `printTreeDown` which (starting at a given `Person`) will print their children, grandchildren, etc.

The main method (which constructs the example family tree) looks like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Person gp0 = new Person("Abraham","Simpson", true);
    Person gp1 = new Person("Penelope","Olsen", false);

    Person gp2 = new Person("Pan","Bouvier", true);
    Person gp3 = new Person("Jackie","Bouvier", false);

    Person p0 = new Person("Herb","Powers", true);
    gp0.addChild(p0);
    gp1.addChild(p0);

    Person p1 = new Person("Homer","Simpson", true);
    gp0.addChild(p1);
    gp1.addChild(p1);

    Person p2 = new Person("Marge","Bouvier", false);
    gp2.addChild(p2);
    gp3.addChild(p2);

    Person p3 = new Person("Selma","Bouvier", true);
    gp2.addChild(p3);
    gp3.addChild(p3);

    Person c0 = new Person("Bart", "Simpson", true);
    p1.addChild(c0);
    p2.addChild(c0);

    // your code goes here
    c0.printTreeUp();
}
```

It outputs the family tree (up) for `Bart Simpson` and looks like this:

```
 Bart Simpson ♂  
    ∟ Homer Simpson ♂  
        ∟ Abraham Simpson ♂  
        ∟ Penelope Olsen ♀  
    ∟ Marge Bouvier ♀  
        ∟ Pan Bouvier ♂  
        ∟ Jackie Bouvier ♀
```